# Why is !true ? 'false' : 'true' returning 'true'?

Tags: javascript

Why is it that when I do

```
(!true) ? 'false' : 'true'
```

it returns `'true'`?

Comment: FYI, if you're happen to want the string 'true' or 'false' from a variable, you can also type: `!var+''` (or `!!var+''` if you want it flipped)

Comment: What did you expect it to return?

Comment: Why hasn't this question contains an **accepted** answer?

Comment: @Buhake, maybe JM at Work was confused by the opening parenthesis without a closing one and did not want to accept?

Comment: @Sebastian Langer, Aaah! Well spotted, 2 years after posting the original answer! Thanks! :-)

Comment: It is funny, that we now have the least and the highest scoring answers showing the same code. One of the answers should remove the parentheses at all to show some variety. :-) It would still be valid code.

Comment: @djangofan Because the OP of the question hasn't been online at StackOverflow since the end of 2011. Odds are this question will remain unanswered.

Answer (score 66):

It simply means

```
if (!true) {
  return 'false';
} else {
  return 'true';
}
```

`!true` (not true) means `false`, so the `else` is returned.

Answer (score 23):

The syntax of `A ? B : C` means that if A is TRUE, then return the value B.  Else return value C.  Since A is `FALSE`, it returns the value C which happens to be `true`.

Answer (score 21):

Because `(!true)` is false, and then the right side of the `:` is chosen.

Comment: True is false and false is true. WAT

Answer (score 17):

Because the above is equivalent to:

```
if (false) {
    return 'false';
} else {
    return 'true';
}
```

Though perhaps the confusion is coming from the difference between:

```
if (false) // which is false
```

And

```
if (false == false) // which is true
```

Comment: I think you mean 'true' there ;)

Comment: you mean `else { return 'true'; }` :)

Comment: I also believe that's exactly the case

Answer (score 7):

This can be expanded to:

```
if(!true){
   return 'false';
} else {
   return 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(!true)` is equivalent to `if(!true= true)` which is equivalent to `if(false=true)` which is `false`. Therefore `return (true)` which is on the false side of the `if` statement.

Comment: You can't set true equal to false. At least in sane languages.

Comment: I think you mean `if(!true==true)`

Comment: JS is a sane language: `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`

Answer (score 1):

The confusion lies here because of the use of string literals to represent boolean values. If you reverse the `'false'` and `'true'`, it makes more sense:

`(!true) ? 'true' : 'false'`

Would return the string literal `false`, which is much different than a `boolean` value.

Your original statement `(!true) ? 'false' : 'true'` reads as

> "If not true, then return the string literal true".

The statement I posted first reads as

> "If not true, then return the string literal false".

Which, if you know the opposite (**not**) value of *true* is *false*, then it explains the logic illustrated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const test = true; // change this value to see the result change  
 
 if (!test) { // if test is NOT truthy
     console.log('false')
 } else { // if test === true
     console.log('true')
 }
```

```
// Since in the original question a ternary expression was used, the above code is equivalent to this:

!test ? console.log('false') : console.log('true');
```