# Why !{}[true]; gives true in Javascript console

Tags: javascript

I saw this strange piece of code `!{}[true];` today. When you run this code snippet, it returns true.

What full `!{}[true]` means and why it returns true.

```
>>>!{}[true];
'true'
```

Comment: Why do you have to ask a question that was asked barely a few hours back?

Comment: This was asked only 5 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702805/why-does-true-evaluate-to-true-in-javascript

Comment: my bad, I did a Google search and didn't find answer at that time, that's why posted. and now I lost 5 points of my meager 126 :(

Comment: U can remove this question to restore ur points. As already indicated, it has been answered just a few hours back.

Answer (score 2):

`{}[true]` returns `undefined` because `{}` has no property `"true"` (`!{"true":25}[true]` would return `false`).

So `!{}` is `true`.

Comment: Amazing to see answers rolling by...

Comment: @devnull I didn't see the duplicate, I voted to close since.

Comment: .. for a question that's being already voted to be closed as a dup of one that was asked a few hours back ..

Comment: @devnull I answered before it was voted to close. Please refrain from insulting comments.

Comment: Apologies if I sounded rude, that was not the intent.  I was more peeved at the question.  It's the same question that currently on the top of the hot questions list.

Comment: And since your answer has an upvote, OP can't delete the question.  I'm pleased :) +1

Comment: @devnull I wasn't lucky enough to see the precedent one (I never look at the hot questions list). In any case it didn't merit so much upvotes, that's just a useless puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Negate an object?  How exactly do you negate an object?

In any case, start with `{}[true]`.  What that does is create a new object, and reference its `true` member, which doesn't exist, so returns undefined.

So then you have `!undefined`, which evaluates to `true`.

Comment: *"How exactly do you negate an object?"* All JavaScript values have a Boolean equivalent, so all values can be negated.

Comment: @BlueSkies True.  The object would be truthy, so negating would be false.  The phrase made me think there was some other intent, and I didn't stop to think it through.

Comment: I think we can negate, `var obj = { one: 1, two: 2 }; >>>!obj >>>false'

Comment: @Varun Only in the sense Blue Skies and I mentioned.  It's not invalid syntax, but I was curious if your understanding matched what happens.  You can put `if (myObject)` as an if statement, and it will return true as long as myObject is not undefined or null (or an empty string or a zero number).  You can't exactly negate an object, but you can negate the logical evaluation of one.  That is, `myObject = !myObject` is not a syntax error, but almost certainly doesn't do what you want.  And in this example, it wouldn't follow the typical rule of negation, that `!!object === object`.

Comment: @Varun `if (!myObject)` would look at the truthiness of `if (myObject)` and negate that, returning a boolean.  If you did do something like `myObject = !myObject`, and myObject wasn't originally a boolean, you'd be taking an object and converting it to false.  You may have known all that, but the phrase "negate an object" made me wonder.

Comment: I am learning Javascript and your explanation made few things clear, thanks a lot.